# (solved ) Convert MP3 to Wav using FFMPEG, without trimming silence?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion

I am used to convert all my audio and video stuff with FFMPEG bat files because it's convenient.

I am currently using `ffmpeg -i "%1"  %~dpn1.wav` in a Drag-and-Drop bat file, which does convert MP3 (and others) to WAV, but unfortunately the few milliseconds of silence at either end of the sound seem to be discarded. At the very least the sound length is no longer the same.

Is there a way to make FFMPEG output the exact same lenght without trimming any parts of the sound?

Answer:
Thanks to Ricardo Bohner, who suggested adding `-ss 00:00:00` to the mix, turning the code into `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i "%1"  %~dpn1.wav`

-c copy was also suggested, but somehow didn't work. It also made Audacity unable to open the converted sound file, while Adobe audition still managed to do so.

Comment: Could this answer answer your question? [Use FFMPEG to export audios with gaps filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845150/use-ffmpeg-to-export-audios-with-gaps-filled#52847587)

Answer (score 0):

Only `-c copy` option can guarantee the input and output streams has the same data / duration:

```
ffmpeg -i "%1" -c copy %~dpn1.wav
```

Any codec conversion (like skipping `-c` option entirely or use any other option than `-c copy`) can lead you to some differences between input and output. On the other hand, the above command will not work in cases where `wav` format will not be able to use the codec from the input file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this also trimmed data from the beginning of the sound.

Comment: @MrFunreal Can you show the output from `ffmpeg -i filename` from some examples of the input and the output files?

Comment: ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i "%1"  %~dpn1.wav

Comment: @RicardoBohner Do you think that overwriting the default `0` for `-ss` with the same value should change anything? On the other hand we still do not know the report what are the input / output files.

Comment: I don't know, it's woth a try as he claims some silent is missing in the beginning of the file -ss 00:00:00 takes the source file from possition 0 to end, I don't know if that is the default already...

Comment: @Alain1A45 I'm not sure, your example isn't copying but re-encoding. It could work but if `-c copy` doesn't then I suppose that maybe MrFunreal's files are some unusual ones. I'm still waiting to see his report from the input and the output.

Comment: Hey. I'm sorry for the late reply. Ricardo's answer of using `-ss 00:00:00` worked properly. The sounds themselves shouldn't be "unusual". since they're just recordings of engine noises from a game, which I had used ffmpeg to only keep the audio from the videos.

Comment: @MrFunreal: That's the reason why I asked about the reports from some examples of the files you are using. In most cases ffmpeg will have no problem to "copy" audio streams, recordings are one of the unusual examples where such problems can exist.